# Teams::AdaptiveCard: Why my card's content could not be displayed?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.

The app has attachments functionality which is built based on the task module.
To upload/download attachment we make an AdaptiveCard and add Submit.Action with msteams object and add out object to it. Example:

> "data": {"msteams": {"type": "task/fetch"}, "mmt": {"type": "attachments/upload"}}

Everything worked fine till the 10th of September, when the Teams Desktop Apps stopped rendering our cards (iOS and Android continued working):

[image]

After an investigation we've found that Action.Submit caused it. Here's the Action data:

```
{
    "type": "Action.Submit",
    "title": "Upload image",
    "data": {
        "mmt": {
            "id": 101,
            "type": "bur/kek",
            "contentType": "hi/microsoft"
        },
        "msteams": {
            "type": "task/fetch"
        }
    }
},
```

The issue is caused by these lines:

```
"id": 101,
"type": "bur/kek"
```

If we change **id** from type **int** to **string** or rename field "**type**" to "**anyType**" the issue does not appear.

So this looks like a BUG to me.

Comment: to clarify,
do previously submitted cards render properly ?

Comment: No, the old cards that were sent before the 10th of September have stopped to render.

Comment: devsupport's  minimal repro that fails to render in teams client is https://gist.github.com/Josverl/c6adb82cc83d50e60fd4f449b0d046ee
does that match the structure and AC version you are using , 
if not , can you please provide a more complete sample ?

Comment: Yes just tried to send this card. Same result, not rendering.

Answer (score 1):

We are able to repro the issue. Sending card having `"id"` as `int` isn't rendering. I faced no issue if I make `"id"` as string and `"type"` as `"bur/kek"`.

We have raised a bug for this. Internal team is looking into it. I will update you one it is fixed or if we got update from them.

Comment: @Oleksa-Bug is resolved. Could you please check it once?